# mpdf get total page number in pdf body (not in header/footer)

Tags: php, pdf, mpdf

I need to get total number of pages in pdf in pdf body. I can get total or current page number in footer by writing:

```
{PAGENO}/{nb}
```

but I need total number of pages in body:

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
$mpdf->SetHtmlHeader($header, 'OE');
$mpdf->SetHTMLFooter($footer, 'OE');
$mpdf->AddPage('', // L - landscape, P - portrait 
            '', '', '', '', 20, // margin_left
            20, // margin right
            5, // margin top
            25, // margin bottom
            10, // margin header
            10); // margin footer
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html); //here comes the html of pdf body and i need total pages count in it.
$mpdf->Output($title . '.pdf', 'd');
```